# Scanner input issues

Tags: java

I want to merge a CSV file with a batch file I wrote to make an installer for all the printers at my office. The xeroxTemplate.txt file is a batch file I renamed as a txt in case that was causing formatting issues.

When run, it throws the following error for the first "for" loop. I confirmed that the file does have contents

`java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`

```
public class PrinterScriptCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner csvScanner = new Scanner("printers.csv");
        csvScanner.useDelimiter(",");
        Scanner txtScanner = new Scanner("xeroxTemplate.txt");

        try{
            while(csvScanner.hasNext()){
                //create file with name from first csv cell
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(csvScanner.next());
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
                //copy first 7 lines from xeroxTemplate.txt
                for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
                    pw.println(txtScanner.nextLine());
                }
                //copy the next three cells from CSV into new file
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                    pw.println(csvScanner.next());
                }
                //copy remaining lines from TXT to the new file
                while(txtScanner.hasNextLine()){
                    pw.println(txtScanner.nextLine());
                }
            }  
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s\n", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The stacktrace will tell you what line the error occurred on. Find it and highlight it (by adding a comment) in the code you pasted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are instantiating the Scanner object, the String you pass to the constructor is considered the content that needs to be parsed.

```
Scanner csvScanner = new Scanner("printers.csv");
Scanner txtScanner = new Scanner("xeroxTemplate.txt");
```

Here it is trying to parse the string "printers.csv" using the delimiter ",".  As there are no "," in the string, it fails when you are trying to read the second and subsequent values in the below code.

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    w.println(csvScanner.next());
}
```

If you are using Scanner to read a file, one option is to pass the file object to the constructor of Scanner.

Try this,

```
File file = new File("printers.csv");
Scanner csvScanner = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: It would help if you told the OP what they are doing wrong. In this case, the filename is being used as the input value rather than being treated as a file as they believe, and maybe mention that they've done this twice.

Comment: That solved it and I understood your explanation. Thanks!